# How to copy a pointer to incomplete type - C++

Tags: c++, pointers, deep-copy, sdl-2, incomplete-type

I'm trying to copy the contents of the pointer `myTexture` into the pointer `texture` (a class member), as shown in the code below:

```
Sprite::Sprite(SDL_Renderer *renderer, SDL_Texture *myTexture) {

    // Initialize texture
    this->texture = myTexture;
}
```

However, I need to have `texture` not just point to the same object as `myTexture`, because I want to be able to modify `texture` without affecting `myTexture` as well. I have tried using the copy constructor, but the compiler says that incomplete types are not allowed. I'm not really sure as to how I can create a copy of this object without pointing to the same object.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You tried `this->texture = new SDL_Texture(*myTexture);` and it didn't work?

Comment: @MattPhillips Yep: `incomplete type is not allowed`. I don't know much about how to get around incomplete types.

Comment: Is there any problem in including the definition of `SDL_Texture`? Why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: @MattPhillips: When the type is incomplete, then you cannot access any member, including the constructor. For what you know, an accessible constructor may not even exist.

Comment: @RSahu It's part of a lib, so I'm pretty sure I can't do that, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @idtownie, you should be use the definition of the class from the library. If not, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot call the copy constructor, or generally access any member of an incomplete type. After all, that's what makes it incomplete; you are not supposed to know that the type even supports copying, or anything else.

I'd say just include the whole type rather than just forward-declaring it, and be done with it.

---

**Edit:** I might add that we are talking about an SDL texture type here. [This type](http://fossies.org/dox/SDL2-2.0.3/structSDL__Texture.html) doesn't look like it even supports copying. It has, for example, "prev" and "next" pointers, and a pointer which seems to point back to a renderer object. Hardly a value class.

It looks like you should reconsider your design as a whole here, and the real question is not about incomplete types but "How to copy `SDL_Texture` contents."

Comment: I would do that, but the type SDL_Texture is part of a lib, so I didn't think that I would be able to do that. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @idtownie: I would guess that you can include a corresponding header file but that the type doesn't support copying. It's been a long time since I used SDL, but a texture doesn't feel like being copyable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. It's not exactly copying the pointer, but what I did is, because I'm using SDL2, I changed the render target to `this->texture`, and then used `SDL_RenderCopy()` to put the original texture on the new one. This was the easiest solution I found, unfortunately.